# Buscando palavras separadas na mesma string no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, string, algoritmo-de-busca

Minha pergunta é relativamente simples, mas não consegui achar uma resposta que realmente me ajudasse:

Meu usuário faz uma busca por um nome em um formulário: **Fulano Silva**

O registro em meu banco está como **Fulano de Tal Silva**

```
SELECT * FROM `dados` WHERE `nome` LIKE '%".Fulano Silva."%'
```

Ao realizar a busca com PHP no MySQL por Fulano Silva usando LIKE ele não conseguirá encontrar o registro!

Se ele tivesse buscado **apenas por Fulano** ou por **apenas por Silva**, ele encontraria, mas pelo fato de ter mais strings entre Fulano e Silva (de Tal) o registro não é encontrado.

Como posso resolver essa situação? Devo separar as strings na frase e procurá-las individualmente? Como poderia fazer isso? Obrigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Coloque `%` entre todas as palavras a serem filtradas:

```
SELECT * FROM `dados` WHERE `nome` LIKE '%".Fulano%Silva."%'
```

Coloquei um exemplo no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa2eb6/1) pra você ver funcionando

Comment: ... que pode ser feito através do `str_replace()`: `str_replace(' ', '%', $texto);`

Comment: Downvoter, pode comentar?

Comment: Por que o voto negativo?

Comment: Também não sei, estou esperando explicação :/

Comment: @ArturTrapp funcionou perfeitamente, era o que eu estava precisando.